# How to update component state in React Route

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I authenticate a user using localStorage. It's working fine. But after authenticating the authenticated component is not loading. state is not changing. The state is changing if i reload the page.

This is App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './components/Header';
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Sign from './components/users/sign'
import Dashboard from './components/Admin/Dashboard';
import UpdateProduct from './components/Admin/UpdateProduct';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import ParticularProduct from './components/ParicularProduct'
import ViewProducts from './components/Admin/ViewProducts';
import Cart from './components/Cart';
import AdminWelcome from './components/Admin/AdminWelcome';
import Search from './components/common/Search';
import AllProducts from './components/AllProducts';
import UserOptions from './components/UserOptions';
import { decodeToken } from 'react-jwt';


function App() {

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const user = decodeToken(localStorage.getItem("token"))
const auth = ()=>{
  if(user){
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    console.log(isAuthenticated);
  }
}


  useEffect(()=>{
    WebFont.load({
      google:{
        families:["Roboto"]
      }
    })
    auth();
    console.log(isAuthenticated);
  }, [isAuthenticated,user]);

  return (
    <>
    <ToastContainer />
     <Header />
     {isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} />}
     <Routes>
     <Route path='/' Component={Home} />
     <Route path='/products/:id' element={<ParticularProduct />} />
     <Route path='/search' element={<Search />} />
     <Route path='/product' element = {<AllProducts />} />
     <Route path="/product/:keyword" element = {<AllProducts />} />
      <Route path="/account" Component={Sign}>
      <Route path="createproduct" Component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path='/account' element={<AdminWelcome />} />
        <Route path="updateproduct/:id" element={<UpdateProduct />} />
        <Route path='viewproducts' element={<ViewProducts />} />
      </Route>
      {/* <Route path='/products/:id/cart' element={<Cart />} /> */}
      <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
     </Routes>
     <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is UserOptions.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SpeedDial, SpeedDialAction } from "@mui/material";
import { RiDashboard2Fill} from "react-icons/ri";
import {ImExit} from "react-icons/im";
import {BsFillPersonFill} from "react-icons/bs";
import {FaShoppingCart} from "react-icons/fa"

const UserOptions = ({user}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const options = [
    { icon: <BsFillPersonFill />, name: user.name },
    { icon: <ImExit />, name: "Logout", func:logoutUser },
    { icon: <FaShoppingCart />, name: "Cart" },
  ];

    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
        // const user = decodeToken(token);
    //    user.isAdmin ? options.unshift({icon:<RiDashboard2Fill />, name:"Dashboard"}):""
    if(user.isAdmin){
        options.unshift({icon:<RiDashboard2Fill />, name:"Dashboard"})
    }

    function logoutUser(){
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        window.location.reload();
    }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <SpeedDial
          ariaLabel="myDial"
          onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
          onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
          open={open}
          icon={<img src={"Profile.png"} className="w-full" />}
          direction="down"
          className=" fixed top-3 right-3"
        >
          {options.map((item)=>(
            <SpeedDialAction icon={item.icon} tooltipTitle={item.name} onClick={item.func} key={item.name} />
          ))}
        </SpeedDial>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserOptions;
```

After Login and Logout UserOptions component not loading automatically. I have to reload the page. Like i done in "logout" function in UserOptions.jsx. But i don't want to reload the page. I want it will render automatically.

Please Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well you want this effect to fire when the App component mounts, we make `user` a useState hook instead, then set it based on `token` definition:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    WebFont.load({
        google: {
            families: ['Roboto'],
        },
    });
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        const decodedUser = decodeToken(token);
        setUser(decodedUser);
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
    } 
}, []);
```

and these are the two functions to handle user login/logout:

```js
const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    setUser(null);
};

const handleLogin = (token) => {
    const decodedUser = decodeToken(token);
    setUser(decodedUser);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
};
```

just pass them as props to the appropriate component:

```js
isAuthenticated && <UserOptions user={user} handleLogin={handleLogin} handleLogout={handleLogout}/>}
```

you may need to pass only the `handleLogout` function